# using countif and count in vba macro from different sheet but getting error Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using `COUNTIF` and `COUNTA` in VBA macro from different sheets but getting error

> Subscript out of range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B8").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('Raw data'![B:B]-1)"
  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C8").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF('Raw data'![M:M],""Suppress"")"
  Range("C9").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: in which worksheet event is this code placed ? in "Sheet4" ?

Comment: are your formulas realy changing ? you are looking to use R1C1 ? since you are using these formulas only on Cells B8 and C8 in Sheet4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the selection in a macro that is called when the selection changes, so it forms an infinite loop.

You are also mixing R1C1 notation and column letter notation.

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B8").Formula = "=COUNTA('Raw data'!B:B)-1"
  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C8").Formula = "=COUNTIF('Raw data'!M:M,""Suppress"")"
End Sub
```